# How do I edit an external submodule, and push it to my own repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-push, git-fork

I am working on my thesis, where I extend another paper. This paper has made all their code public in repo X, also using a submodule themselves: let's call that one Y.

For my own project, I have made an own repo Z in which I have included X as a submodule, and thus Y as a nested submodule. However, I would like to make changes to the code in X and Y, and also be able to push this to my own repo so that I can use it at multiple locations. I do not have push permission to X and Y since it is someone elses repo. What is the best way to go about this?
Thanks in advance, I am lost :D

I tried pushing my own repo in its main directory, but then it does not include the code I changed in the submodules. When I go into the submodules and commit the changed code there, I first gave a warning of a detached head. When I fixed this by checking out to a new branch, it now gives me:

```
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
ERROR: Permission to \[repo X\] denied to \[myusername\].
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I now forked repository X and changed the url in my .gitmodules. What happens to submodule Y now?

Comment: Nothing ever happens to a submodule. It's a different Git repository. In your fork, you can change the contents of the `.gitmodules` file to list a different URL for yet another fork, if you like, or you can leave the existing URL alone, to continue using the same other-Git-repository.

Comment: I now also changed the fork in my .gitmodule in the nested repo. 

But are you saying that if I want to change the contents the two repos by the paper, I need to find a different solution? Could you point me in the right direction there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Let's start with background on submodules

Submodules are simple, but with complicated results.  A "submodule" consists of two parts: there's a `.gitmodules` file, and there are two Git repositories.  One repository is called the *superproject* and one is called the *submodule*.  The superproject contains, in one or more commits, the raw hash ID of a commit to check out *in* the submodule.  That's the entire picture—up until we start actually doing work, anyway.

#### Suppose you start by cloning the superproject

Let's say you run:

```
git clone --no-recurse-submodules <url> super
cd super
```

You now have a commit checked out *in* the superproject repository, complete with an instruction that Git, running *in* this superproject, should check out a commit in the submodule.  But there isn't any submodule.  You've only cloned *one* repository, not two.

The `--no-recurse-submodules` option makes sure that Git doesn't go on to clone the submodule yet.  That's the default anyway, but we made it explicit here on purpose, to make it obvious, and in case you have changed your personal settings to turn on recursion.

You now have to instruct Git to *complete* the checkout, if you'd like the submodule cloned and a commit checked out.  (If you prefer not to bother with the submodule at all, you can leave things in this state: you just won't have a submodule, even though the superproject calls for one.  The actual clone-and-checkout step is optional, provided whatever you're doing doesn't *need* the submodule.  The Git repository for Git, for instance, includes a submodule reference to a program that checks for SHA-1 collisions, but it's specifically *optional* and you don't need to bother with it.)

To complete the checkout, you now run:

```
git submodule update --init
```

(if you use `--recurse-submodules` in your clone, the `git clone` command runs this command for you, after the `git checkout` step, step 6<sup>1</sup>).

There's a problem here: this `git submodule update --init` must run `git clone`.  The `git clone` command needs a *URL*.  Where does the URL come from?  The solution to this problem is the `.gitmodules` file, which must exist in the commit checked out *in* step 6; that file must list the URL(s) for any submodule(s) that must be cloned at this point.

Once those submodules are cloned, the `git submodule update` command—which you may now use without the `--init` flag—picks a commit, by hash ID, that it should `git checkout` *in* each submodule listed by the superproject.  The hash ID that the superproject Git `git submodule update` command checks out *in* the submodule repository is the one stored in the commit checked out (in step 6 again)—or more precisely, the hash ID that is now in Git's *index* (but it got into Git's index via the checkout in step 6).

Any submodules now cloned, via `git submodule update --init`, can *themselves* be superprojects by listing a commit hash ID and having a `.gitmodules` file in them.  If you use the `--recursive` option to `git submodule update`, it will enter each submodule and make it take its own turn as its superproject in command of *its* submodule(s).  So that's the process by which `git clone --recurse-submodules` gets *all* the submodules of submodules of submodules of submodules (however deep the nesting goes).

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git clone` command is basically shorthand for running six or seven commands, all but one of them being Git commands:

1. `mkdir`, or whatever command your system has for making a new folder/directory.  The remaining commands are run *in* the new folder.
2. `git init`: this creates a new, totally empty repository.
3. `git remote add`: this adds the remote whose name you may select, but everyone uses the default `origin`, with the URL you gave to `git clone`.
4. Any `git config` commands you specified (default none).
5. `git fetch origin`: this copies *all the commits* from the Git software that responds at the URL you gave.  It copies *no branches:* their branches become your remote-tracking names instead.
6. `git checkout`: this creates one branch in your new repository, and checks out the commit.  This step is optional as it is suppressed by `--no-checkout`.
7. `git submodule update --init`, if you called for it and if there are submodules listed in the commit checked out in step 6.  This step is optional and is not the default.

---

#### Suppose you *don't* start this way

Imagine that instead of *just* cloning the superproject:

```
git clone --no-recurse-submodules <url> super
cd super
```

you personally first clone the superproject itself, but then you go on to personally clone the submodule too:

```
git clone --no-recurse-submodules <url1> super
cd super
mkdir -p super/sub
git clone --no-recurse-submodules <url2> super/sub
```

Now you can run `git checkout` or `git switch` in `super` (where you are now), and then `git submodule update` in `super`, and Git *does not have to clone a new repository*.  Git just uses the *existing* submodule clone you've made within the superproject.<sup>2</sup>

**When you use this method, the contents of a `.gitmodules` file are ignored.**  So by using this method you don't have to fix any `.gitmodules` files in any superproject, to use a different submodule URL.

---

<sup>2</sup>You might wish to also run `git submodule absorbgitdirs` after the two `git clone` commands, so as to switch from the old Git 1.x model of submodule storage to the new Git 2.x model.  It's not *required*, it's just a good idea for somewhat messy "submodules might come and go and then come back again" reasons.  When submodules *do* go away—e.g., by extracting a historical commit—the result is currently quite ugly: submodules have a lot of user-experience warts, leading many to *still* call them *sob*-modules, despite the major improvements in them since the early days of Git.

---

#### The consequences

What does this all mean?  Well, let's say there's some existing superproject that you don't need to touch, but you have a submodule, or a submodule *of* a submodule, that you *do* need to touch, and as a result, you want people to clone your submodule, or your sub-sub-module, when they clone the superproject.

All you *really* **have** to do is make your own Git repository accessible.  Those "in the know" can carefully clone *your* submodule and put it in place in the superstructure(s) provided by the existing superproject(s).  But if you want it to be *convenient* for others to clone a superproject (only), and have that superproject's `git submodule update --init` clone *your* submodule, you must update the `.gitmodules` file in any Git repository that acts as a superproject for your submodule.

Let's say that you have this structure initially:

```
super                <-- their superproject
super/sub1           <-- their submodule
super/sub1/sub2      <-- their sub-submodule
```

There are two `.gitmodules` files, one in `super/sub1/.gitmodules` that lists the URL from which one can clone `sub2`, and one in `super/.gitmodules` that lists the URL from which one can clone `sub1`.

Because you've made a new repository that *replaces* `sub2`, you must now make a new repository that *replaces* `sub1`, in which the `.gitmodules` file *in* `sub1` lists the new URL for your replacement `sub2`.  But to get the superproject `super` to list the new URL for your replacement `sub1`, you must now make a new repostiory that *replaces* `super`, in which the `.gitmodules` file *in* `super` lists the new URL for your `sub1` replacement.

In other words, the need to touch `.gitmodules` files "bubbles up" from the lowest submodule, through every intermediate submodule, and eventually reaches the topmost superproject.  This is inevitable *if* you want to make it convenient for others to clone *your* bottom-level submodule.

But that's an *if*.  Submodules are already horrible; what's another level of horrible-ness here?  You can, instead of duplicating other repositories just to update one `.gitmodules` file in each one, provide an instruction that, after doing a recursive clone or `update --init`, those who want to use your sub-sub-module should remove the one clone and replace it with yours.

It's your choice: make it convenient for others by making it inconvenient for you, or make it more convenient for you by making it inconvenient for others.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super extensive answer! This has given me a way better understanding of the working of submodules.